# DCC Error ...: E2010 Incompatible types: 'integer' and 'Integer'

Tags: delphi, generics, interface, delphi-xe

Attempting to build an interface and generics based graph and getting an odd error - note the case difference in the word 'integer' in  the error line.

The text parser is passed to a Graph implementation and then called by the Graph to build its base data structure. Further IGraphConstructor objects can build 
more complex actual graphs and not just populate the base dictionary.

```
IGraphConstructor<K,V> = interface
  function Construct(AData : TObjectDictionary<K,V>) : boolean;
end;

IGraph<K,V> = interface
  ['{B25EEE1F-3C85-43BB-A56B-3E14F7EA926C}']
  function Construct(AConstructor : IGraphConstructor<K,V>) : boolean;
  function GetNodes : TObjectDictionary<K,V>;
  property Nodes : TObjectDictionary<K,V> read GetNodes;
end;

TGraph<K,V> = class(TComponent, IGraph<K,V>)
private
  FData : TObjectDictionary<K,V>;
  function GetNodes : TObjectDictionary<K,V>;
... 

//the editor
TVirtualEditor = class(TComponent)
private
  FGlyphs : TGraph<integer,TGlyph>;
...  

TTextParser<integer,TGlyph> = class(TInterfacedObject, IGraphConstructor<integer,TGlyph>)
...
```

and...

```
function TVirtualEditor.Edit(AText: string): boolean;
var
  parser : TTextParser<integer,TGlyph>;
begin
  parser := TTextParser<integer,TGlyph>.Create(AText);
  result := FGlyphs.Construct(parser);
end;

function TTextParser<integer,TGlyph>.Construct(AData: TObjectDictionary<integer,TGlyph>): boolean;
var
  i : integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to length(FText) do
  begin
    //#1
    AData.AddOrSetValue(i, TGlyph(TCharGlyph.Create( FText[i] )) ); //!--> error [DCC Error] ...: E2010 Incompatible types: 'integer' and 'Integer'
  end;

  //uc....

end;
```

Declaring TTextParser as `TTextParser<K,V>` and using it as

```
TParser : TTextParser<integer,TGlyph>;
```

returns and error at #1 of

```
[DCC Error] ...: E2010 Incompatible types: 'K' and 'Integer'
```

---

**EDIT: Workaround**

Found a workaround but not sure that's the way to do it.

```
function TTextParser<K,V>.Construct(AData: TObjectDictionary<K,V>): boolean;
var
  i : integer;
  n : K;
  o : V;
begin
  for i := 1 to length(FText) do
  begin
    n := K((@i)^);
    o := V(TCharGlyph.Create( FText[i] ));
    AData.AddOrSetValue(n, o );
  end;
  result := true;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
TTextParser<integer,TGlyph> = class(TInterfacedObject, IGraphConstructor<integer,TGlyph>)
```

describes a generic type where the two used generic type names are *integer* and *TGlyph* (like *K* and *V* are in `IGraph<K,V>`). Those are only placeholders and should not be confused with the existing types `integer` and `TGlyph`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you wanted to achieve some special behaviour if `K` is integer. This is called **specialization** and is possible in C++ ([link to MSDN magazine article covering template specialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163754.aspx)), but not in Delphi. It is best to avoid such specializations and just work with the generic type `K` (this should be easy, otherwise the generic class does not make much sense in the first place).

There is a workaround if you really need a special case: you can then compare the type infos (you need to include unit `TypInfo`for this):

```
if (TypeInfo(K) = TypeInfo(Integer)) then
  begin
  // special case
  end;
```

Comment: Correct - I changed the approach because of that